# Why two elements in an array when only one assignment?

Tags: php, arrays

In my PHP(5.4.19) app, I assigned string values to two different arrays.  One array is scoped to the method, and the other array is a class property:

```
class AnyClass{
   public $foo = array();

   public function anyMethod(){
       $bar = array();
       $bar[]       = 'anyTextA';
       $this->foo[] = 'anyTextB';
       return array( $bar, $this->foo );
   }
}
```

Here is what anyMethod() returns:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => anyTextA
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => anyTextB
                [1] => anyTextB
            )

    )
```

Why are two elements appearing in the second array when only one assignment has taken place?

Comment: And you are you instantiating this?

Comment: Please show more code. Like where you call the method... It is likely you are calling the method twice.

Comment: Every time you call the method, there will be more elements in the second array.

Comment: You're probably calling the method twice. See this [demo](http://3v4l.org/WsFaf).

Comment: Do like this, `$this->foo = array();$this->foo[] = 'anyTextB';` then see output, it will initialize it to blank array

Comment: Problem will be in your method calling. How did you called your method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be calling this method more than 1 time.

```
$this->foo[] = 'anyTextB';
```

This statement `adds` one more entry to `$this->foo` whereas the other statement `$bar = array();` creates a new array everytime. So if you run this method two times, you will get two values for `$foo` but still one value for `$bar`.

As I asked in the first comment, if you show us how you are creating an instance of that class we will be better able to tell exactly where are you duplicating the call.

Contrary to what is being suggested elsewhere, do ***not*** use `$this->foo=array();`. Debug your issue and resolve what's wrong, rather than just putting up a temporary fix to hide the mistake and build more code upon it.

Comment: Sometimes I seriously think of deleting answers where the OP has no interest whatsoever in the discussion and we keep wasting our time here.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method twice.

This could be because you are calling the method before AND while you are trying to echo the results.

But it could also be because you are working in an IDE, and the IDE has the method set in the Watch list, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You may be call `anyMethod()` twice.

Try to add an index in the array `foo`.

For example: `$this->foo[1] = 'anyTextB';`

The problem should not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

The number of assignments in your `$foo` array depends on the number of times the `anyMethod()` gets executed

i.e. if `anyMethod()` gets executed once, it will contain only one value inside and if `anyMethod()` gets executed 5 times, it will contain 5 values inside

As your `$foo` array is scoped outside the `anyMethod()`, values get added to it every time you execute the `anyMethod()` function

But in case of the `$bar` array, its scoped inside the `anyMethod()`. It initializes the `$bar` to a new array every time the `anyMethod()` executes

If you want to avoid this problem

use this line `$foo = array();` inside your `anyMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this .. and you will get what you are expecting to get.

```
$var = new AnyClass;
var_dump($var->anyMethod());
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "anyTextA"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "anyTextB"
  }
}
```

Comment: Add another `var_dump()` below that and you'll see the output that the OP sees.

Comment: Exactly. The question is `Why are two elements appearing in the second array when only one assignment has taken place?` -- I think the answer to that question is - *because you're calling the method twice*. :)